# Software Recommendations: make a flyover video from GPX log?

Tags: software-recommendations, gpx, google-earth-pro, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I m trying to make a video similar to this (at 53 seconds): https://youtu.be/OEU5BCZV6Sc?t=53 from GPX logs we have from our drone. Google Earth Pro software doesn't allow nearly enough customization, but I'm new to all of this and haven't been able to find what I should use. Paid software is fine as well.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour] for details on the way our "Focused question/Best answer" model operates. The [softwarerecs.se] group exists for software recommendations, which helps us focus on questions that don't generate lists of opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell how that video was created, but you should be able to do something pretty similar with a combination of several techniques in Google Earth Pro.  I'll list the general steps here, and you should be able to find more detailed instructions on each piece in the online documentation.

- Import your GPX file into Earth Pro (drag/drop works), and check the boxes to generate both a "Track" and a "LineString", but NOT to "adjust the altitudes to ground height".
- Test playing back the track with the timeline play button, and watch the icon move. Click the wrench icon on the timeline to adjust the playback speed. Expand the folders in the Places panel to select only the Line/Path, or only the Track, or only the Points.
- Optional: Edit the KML file to replace the icon with a 3D model of your aircraft (may require hand-editing the KML?)
- Go to the Options/Preferences/Settings dialog (on PC it's in Tools menu > Options;  on a Mac, I think it's called Preferences?)
- Select the Touring tab and look at the section "When creating a tour from a line".
- Set your tilt angle (about 45 degrees?), a close-in Camera Range (5 to 50m?), and a speed somewhere in the middle. Close Options dialog.
- Go to the section "When creating a tour from a Track", and set the speed multiplier to something pretty high (to start off).
- Close the Options/Settings/Preferences dialog
- Make sure the folders created in your Places list are expanded. Turn on only the Track (not Line or Points), and select the Track (blue highlight).
- Go to the toolbar at the bottom of the Places panel, and find the "Play Tour" button (on the right, with 3 dots connected by a line and a play arrow). Click it and wait for the tour to start!
- You can pause, replay, speed up, etc with the tour control at the bottom of the screen.
- If necessary, adjust settings and re-record the tour until you're happy with it.
- Save the tour as a KML to your my places (Save button on right of tour control). Close the tour control.
- If desired, you can speed things up even more by using the record tour button to record a new tour, while playing back your initial tour at 2x or faster speed. Make sure to save and close the new tour before continuing.
- Go to Tools menu > Movie Maker. Select "Record From > A saved tour", and then select your new tour.
- Set your desired output location & file, the video settings, and click "Create Movie".
- Wait for it to render out your movie file. It actually waits for the data to fully load for each frame of the video, so your end result is super smooth, without any missing imagery/data.

If you want to get more advanced, check out "Google Earth Studio", which just became available for public testing, and lets you generate super high quality video flights for integration with video editing software.